# Ignore param, if not present, in Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I wrote a php function in controller `getItems`, to get all the items when I call through ajax using javascript/jquery. I am passing a param `limit` to limit the items to get from server.

This works fine but how to use the same method to get all the items? Currently, the below query is working if and only if I provide `limit` param value.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT name, id from TABLE_NAME
        ORDER BY shared_date DESC
        LIMIT @~~limit~~@";
```

How to get all the items by modifying the same query?

Currently, I am solving this by having two different queries, one with limit and other without limit. (*which I feel messy*)

Comment: How are you building your query?

Comment: @Cerbrus I have not much idea about it but with help of my colleague (_who is bit busy_) he said that it is build on a custom build query used in our office.

Comment: That doesn't answer _"how"_, though. What code are you using to add that parameter to the query?

Comment: @Cerbrus please leave that the way I get the param. Can you please tell me get what I want using just mysql query?

Comment: The problem is that SQL _really_ isn't the place to handle parameters like that. That should be fixed in the code that builds the query, instead. Still,, I made you a suggestion.

Comment: @Cerbrus I am ok with PHP. how to do it in php? I don't want to write same query twice with limit and without limit.

Comment: We can't tell you how to do it since you are unwilling to show us how you add that parameter to the query. We can't "fix" code we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set the limit as an optional argument in `getItems`.
For example something like this:

```
function getItems($limit=false){
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT name, id from TABLE_NAME
    ORDER BY shared_date DESC "
    if($limit){
        $sql .= "LIMIT $limit";
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't know if you were going to submit the query in a prepared statement or not, so I left it like this (sql-injectable)

Answer (score -2):

```
$limit  = '';
if ($paramLimit != NULL && is_int($paramLimit)) {
   $limit = " LIMIT $paramLimit ";
}

"SELECT DISTINCT name, id from TABLE_NAME
        ORDER BY shared_date DESC
        $limit";
```

Comment: That's just asking for SQL injection.

Comment: He just asked the logic and I put. Its good to remind about sql injection. Remind him about this